# find command - mtime option doesn't work for files older than 25 days

Tags: linux, find

I am using find command to find directories older than 30 days and copy them in other directory.

```
find /STORAGE/RECORDS/XXXXX/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -daystart -mtime +30  -exec cp -rp {} /STORAGE/RECORDS/old_archive_XXXXX/ \;
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work but it looks corect.
When I change the `mtime` option to 25 days it works.

I cant see where is the problem.

Comment: 25 days is maxumum that i can use for mtime - i have try with 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 60, 100

Comment: 25 days is close to the maximum value of an signed 32bit int containing seconds.

Comment: OK but how i can `find` files older than 30 days then

Comment: I saw the problem, it is just me, a mistake with the folders modification time - i have no folders older than 30 days. I dont know how to change the question to solved.